# An inequality for nonnegative symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, symmetric-matrices

Consider $H$ to be a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with nonnegative entries, that has only one positive eigenvalue and other $n-1$ eigenvalues are negative.
I want to prove that for every nonzero and nonnegative real vector $u$ and every real $v$ nonparallel to $u$, it holds:

$(u^T H v)^2 > (u^T H u)(v^T H v)$.

I can't prove the strict inequality, the best I can prove is this:

$(u^T H v)^2 >= (u^T H u)(v^T H v)$.

Is there any hint how to prove the strict version?

So many thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you prove the non-strict inequality? I would suspect that a slight modification of the proof would give you the strict inequality

Comment: @BenGrossmann Actually, I really tried but it doesn't work for strict case. I am even not sure whether the strict one is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. Consider e.g.
$$
H=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&1},\ u=\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ 0},\ v=\pmatrix{0\\ 1\\ -1}.
$$
$H$ has one positive eigenvalue $1+\sqrt{2}$ and two negative eigenvalues $-1,1-\sqrt{2}$. Since $v^THu=0=u^THu$, the strict inequality in question doesn't hold.